# quadratic probing hashmap and its time efficiency

Tags: performance, beginner, c, hash-map

I am writing small a hashmap library (not full featured yet) but I have some questions about the algorithm I wrote, the formula I hope I got right from wikipedia and general things.
Measured ~14.3 million inserts in ~5.3 seconds with a load factor of 0.75, 2.1 s at 0.5.

From the [sparsehash readme](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash/blob/master/README):

> RESOURCE USAGE
>
> - sparse_hash_map has memory overhead of about 4 to 10 bits per
>   hash-map entry, assuming a typical average occupancy of 50%.
> - dense_hash_map has a factor of 2-3 memory overhead: if your
>   hashtable data takes X bytes, dense_hash_map will use 3X-4X memory
>   total.

Why are they talking about *bits* here? Don't we work with bytes?

---

First of all I tested against `rockyou.txt` as it's known to me and has a lot entries. And that's my output:

| Function | Time |
| --- | --- |
| hashdb_test_append_rockyou | 5.309431 sec (Appending 14.344.392 keys to hashdb) |
| hashdb_test_get_key | 0.000005 sec (Get one key) |
| hashdb_test_get_1000_keys | 0.000221 sec (Get 1000 keys) |
| hashdb_test_get_rockyou | 3.330763 sec (Get all keys) |

My `bucket`s only hold a `const char *key` pointer and a `void *value` pointer to store data. Is this common practice or do I need to allocate extra memory for the keys to keep a copy?

EDIT:

I added the source code below. The timebot is a header I've written because I wanted to compare functions that do the same operation to keep track of the time, compare them against each other and now I added some normal timing function to it for hashdb testing.

Default capacity is `7` for testing reasons. Any call on `hashdb_add` calls `hashdb_grow` which tests if it should grow (also checking member `hashdb::constant`). Same for `hashdb_del` and `hashdb_shrink`.

Default load factor of 0.75 used by `hashdb_grow` and `hashdb_shrink`  to check if should grow or shrink.

This is my first hash table implmentation. I now use double hashing + quadratic probing.

I've tested if my formula hit every index and I think it does because I don't get any segmentation fault if I calculate the hash in range of the capacity.

Hope this makes things more clear.

**misc.h** (included by hashdb_internal)

```
#ifndef _HASHDB_MISC_H
#define _HASHDB_MISC_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


/*! @function
 @param     n   number to test if prime
 @return    true if prime, false if not
*/
bool IsPrime(size_t n);

/*! @function
 @param     n   number to get next bigger prime
 @return    next bigger prime number
*/
size_t GetHigherPrime(size_t n);

/*! @function
 @param     n   number to get next bigger prime
 @return    next lower prime number
*/
size_t GetLowerPrime(size_t n);

/*! @function
 @param     str     string to hash
 @return    fnv hash
*/
size_t fnv_hash_string(const char *str);

/*! @function
 @param     data    data to hash
 @param     size    size of data to hash
 @return    fnv hash
*/
size_t fnv_hash(unsigned char *data, size_t size);

/*! @function
 @param     str    string to hash
 @return    elf hash
*/
size_t elfhash(const unsigned char *str);

#endif
```

**misc.c**

```
#include "misc.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037UL
#define FNV_PRIME  1099511628211UL


/* Definition of prime number functions */

/*! @function
 @param     n   number to test
 @return    ture if is prime, false if is not prime
*/
bool IsPrime(size_t n)
{
    if((n & 1) != 0) {
        for(size_t divisor = 3; divisor <= n / divisor; divisor += 2) {
            if((n % divisor) == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return (n == 2);
}

/*! @function
 @param     n   number to get next higher prime from
 @return    next higher prime from n
*/
size_t GetHigherPrime(size_t n) {
    for(size_t i = (n | 1); i < LONG_MAX; i += 2) {
        if(IsPrime(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

/*! @function
 @param     n   number to get next lower prime from
 @return    next lower prime from n
*/
size_t GetLowerPrime(size_t n) {
    for(size_t i = (n | 1); i < LONG_MAX; i -= 2) {
        if(IsPrime(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return n;
}


/* hashing functions */

/*! @function
 @param str null terminated character string to hash
 @return hash in form of size_t
*/
size_t fnv_hash_string(const char *str)
{
    size_t hash;
    int i;
    for(i = 0, hash = FNV_OFFSET; *str != '\0'; str++, i++) {
        hash = hash ^ *str;
        hash = hash * FNV_PRIME;
    }

    return hash;
}

/*! @function
 @param data unsigned byte array
 @param size size of byte array
 @return hash in form of size_t
*/
size_t fnv_hash(unsigned char *data, size_t size)
{
    size_t hash;
    int i;
    for(i = 0, hash = FNV_OFFSET; size != 0; size--, i++) {
        hash = hash ^ *data;
        hash = hash * FNV_PRIME;
    }
    return hash;
}

/*! @function
 @param str null terminated character string to hash
 @return hash in form of size_t
*/
unsigned long elfhash(const unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long   h = 0, high;
    while (*str)
    {
        h = (h << 4) + *str++;
        if ((high = h & 0xF0000000))
            h ^= high >> 24;
        h &= ~high;
    }
    return h;
}
```

**hashdb_internal.h** (included by hashdb)

```
#ifndef _HASHDB_INTERNAL_H
#define _HASHBD_INTERNAL_H

#include "misc.h"

/* definitions */
#define HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAPACITY 7           /* prime number */
#define HASHDB_DEFAULT_LOADFACTOR 0.90     /*  */

/* get index by this ... formular */
#define hash_probe(hash, i, cap) ((hash + (-1) * (i * i + 1) * (i / 2) * (i / 2)) % cap)

/* simple bucket that holds an pointer key as string and pointer to value */
typedef struct bucket {
    const char *key;
    void *value;
} bucket;

/* hashdb holding capacity (number of elements), n (number of elements inside), map (memory location of entries) */
typedef struct hashdb {
    size_t cap;
    size_t n;
    bucket *map;
    bool constant;
} hashdb;

/*! @function
 @param list        pointer to bucket list
 @param capacity    capacity of bucket list
 @param key         key to store
 @param value       value to store by key
 @return            0 if succes, -1 if failure 
*/
int hashdb_insert(bucket *list, size_t capacity, const char *key, void *value);

/*! @function
 @param     list        pointer to list to return from
 @param     capacity    capacity of list
 @param     key         key to get data from
 @return    location of bucket   
*/
bucket* hashdb_return(bucket *list, size_t capacity, const char *key);

/*! @function
 @param old_list    old list with data
 @param old_cap     old_list's capacity
 @param new_list    new_list to insert to
 @param new_cap     new_list's capacity
*/
void hashdb_rehash(bucket *old_list, size_t old_cap, bucket *new_list, size_t new_cap);

/*! @function
 @param db      hashdb pointer
 @param new_cap new capacity
 @return        0 on succes, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_realloc(hashdb *db, size_t new_cap);

/*! @function
 @param db  hashdb pointer
 @return    0 if nothing to allocate or reallocated successfully, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_grow(hashdb *db);

/*! @function
 @param db  hashdb pointer
 @return    0 if nothing to allocate or reallocated successfully, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_shrink(hashdb *db);

/*! @function
 @param str     null terminated string to hash
*/
size_t double_hash(const char *str);


#endif
```

**hashdb_internal.c**

```
#include "hashdb_internal.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

/*! @function
 @param list        pointer to bucket list
 @param capacity    capacity of bucket list
 @param key         key to store
 @param value       value to store by key
 @return            0 if succes, -1 if failure 
*/
int hashdb_insert(bucket *list, size_t capacity, const char *key, void *value)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t hash = double_hash(key);
    size_t probe = 0;

    /* starting at 1 because 1 and 0 would get the same probe so we can safe that step */
    for(i = 1; i <= capacity; i++) {

        probe = hash_probe(hash, i, capacity);

        if(list[probe].key == NULL)
        {
            list[probe].key = key;
            list[probe].value = value;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return -1;    
}


/*! @function
 @param     list        pointer to list to return from
 @param     capacity    capacity of list
 @param     key         key to get data from
 @return    location of bucket   
*/
bucket* hashdb_return(bucket *list, size_t capacity, const char *key)
{

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t probe = 0;
    size_t hash = double_hash(key);

    for(i = 1; i <= capacity; i++) {

        probe = hash_probe(hash, i, capacity);

        if(list[probe].key != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(key, list[probe].key) == 0) {
                return &list[probe];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

/*! @function
 @param old_list    old list with data
 @param old_cap     old_list's capacity
 @param new_list    new_list to insert to
 @param new_cap     new_list's capacity
*/
void hashdb_rehash(bucket *old_list, size_t old_cap, bucket *new_list, size_t new_cap)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < old_cap; i++) {
        if(old_list[i].key != NULL) {
            hashdb_insert(new_list, new_cap, old_list[i].key, old_list[i].value);
        }
    }

}

/*! @function
 @param db      hashdb pointer
 @param new_cap new capacity
 @return        0 on succes, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_realloc(hashdb *db, size_t new_cap)
{
    bucket *new_list = calloc(new_cap, sizeof *db->map);
    if(new_list == NULL) {
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    hashdb_rehash(db->map, db->cap, new_list, new_cap);
    free(db->map);

    db->map = new_list;
    db->cap = new_cap;

    return 0;
}

void hashdb_enable_constant(hashdb *db, bool newval)
{
    db->constant = newval;
}

/*! @function
 @param db  hashdb pointer
 @return    0 if nothing to allocate or reallocated successfully, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_grow(hashdb *db)
{
    if((db->n != (size_t) (db->cap * HASHDB_DEFAULT_LOADFACTOR)) || db->constant == true) {
        return 0;
    }

    size_t new_cap = GetHigherPrime(db->cap * 2);

    if(hashdb_realloc(db, new_cap) != 0) {
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*! @function
 @param db  hashdb pointer
 @return    0 if nothing to allocate or reallocated successfully, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_shrink(hashdb *db)
{
    if(db->cap <= HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAPACITY){
        db->cap = HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
        return 0;
    }

    if((db->n != (size_t) (db->cap * (1 - HASHDB_DEFAULT_LOADFACTOR))) || db->constant == true) {
        return 0;
    }

    size_t new_cap = GetLowerPrime(db->cap / 2);
    if(hashdb_realloc(db, new_cap) != 0) {
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

size_t double_hash(const char *str)
{
    return elfhash((const unsigned char*) str) + fnv_hash_string(str);

}
```

**hashdb.h**

```
#ifndef _HMAP_H
#define _HMAP_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef void hashdb;

hashdb* hashdb_create(void);
void hashdb_destroy(hashdb *db);

void hashdb_enable_constant(hashdb *db, bool newval);
size_t hashdb_cap(hashdb *db);
size_t hashdb_len(hashdb *db);
double hashdb_filled_percent(hashdb *db);

int hashdb_add(hashdb *db, const char *key, const void *data);
void* hashdb_get(hashdb *db, const char *key);
void* hashdb_del(hashdb *db, const char *key);

int hashdb_ensure_capacity(hashdb *db, size_t new_capacity);
/* int hashdb_clear(hashdb *db);
int hashdb_reset(hashdb *db);
int hashdb_hardreset(hashdb *db);

int hashdb_to_json(hashdb *db, const char *path);
int hashdb_from_json(hashdb *db, const char *path);

int hashdb_to_http(hashdb *db, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz);
int hashdb_from_http(hashdb *db, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz);
*/

void hashdb_printall(hashdb *db);



#endif
```

**hashdb.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "hashdb_internal.h"

#define HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAP 7

/*! @function
 @return hashdb pointer
*/
hashdb* hashdb_create()
{
    hashdb *db = calloc(1, sizeof *db);
    if(db == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    db->cap = HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAP;

    db->map = calloc(db->cap, sizeof *db->map);
    if(db->map == NULL) {
        free(db);
        return NULL;
    }

    return db;
}
/*! @function
 @param db  hashdb pointer to destroy
*/
void hashdb_destroy(hashdb *db)
{
    free(db->map);
    free(db);
}

/*! @function
 @param db      hashdb pointer
 @param key     key
 @param value   value associated with key
 @return        0 on success, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_add(hashdb *db, const char *key, void *value)
{
    if(db->n == db->cap) {
        return -1; /* full, should not happen */
    }

    /* check if it should grow */
    if(hashdb_grow(db) != 0) {
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    if(hashdb_insert(db->map, db->cap, key, value)) {
        return -1; /* internal error */
    }

    db->n++;

    return 0;
}

/*! @function
 @param db      hashdb pointer
 @param key     key to retrieve date from
 @return        data associated with key
*/
void* hashdb_get(hashdb *db, const char *key)
{
    bucket *item = hashdb_return(db->map, db->cap, key);
    if(item == NULL) {
        return item; /* not found */
    }

    return item->value;
}

/*! @function
 @param db      hashdb pointer
 @param key     key to retrieve date from
 @return        data associated with key
*/
void* hashdb_del(hashdb *db, const char *key)
{
    bucket *item = hashdb_return(db->map, db->cap, key);
    if(item == NULL) {
        return item;
    }

    void *value = item->value;
    item->key = NULL;
    item->value = NULL;
    db->n--;
    if(hashdb_shrink(db) != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return value;
}

/*! @function
 @param db              hashdb pointer
 @param new_capacity    new number of elements
 @return                0 on succes, ENOMEM on failure
*/
int hashdb_ensure_capacity(hashdb *db, size_t new_capacity)
{
    size_t new_cap = GetHigherPrime(new_capacity);

    if(hashdb_realloc(db, new_cap) != 0) {
        return ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

size_t hashdb_cap(hashdb *db)
{
    return db->cap;
}

size_t hashdb_len(hashdb *db)
{
    return db->n;
}

double hashdb_filled_percent(hashdb *db)
{
    return (double) db->n / db->cap * 100;
}

void hashdb_printall(hashdb *db)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < db->cap; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", db->map[i].key);
    }
}
```

**hashdb_test.c**

```
#include "../../include/hashdb.h"

#include "timebot.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ROCKYOU_PATH "../src/test/data/rockyou.txt"
#define ROCKYOU_LINES 14344392  /* number of lines in rockyou.txt */

#define HASHDB_START_GET_FROM 121512    /* start point for  hashdb_test_get_1000_keys and hashdb_test_get_key*/

char **test_keys = NULL;

/* initialize keys from rockyou.txt */
int init_test_keys(const char *path)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("open file");
        return -1;
    }

    test_keys = calloc(ROCKYOU_LINES, sizeof *test_keys);
    if(test_keys == NULL) {
        perror("init_test_keys");
        return -1;
    }

    char key_buf[128];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ROCKYOU_LINES; i++) {
        fgets(key_buf, sizeof(key_buf), fp);
        key_buf[strlen(key_buf)-1] = '\0';
        test_keys[i] = strdup(key_buf);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void destroy_keys()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ROCKYOU_LINES; i++) {
        free(test_keys[i]);
    }
    free(test_keys);
}

void hashdb_test_fullfill(hashdb *db)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < hashdb_cap(db); i++) {
        if(hashdb_add(db, test_keys[i], test_keys[i]) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_add failed\n");
            abort();
        }
        //printf("adding Key: %s - %s\n", test_keys[i], test_keys[i]);
    }

    char *res = NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < hashdb_cap(db); i++) {
        res = hashdb_get(db, test_keys[i]);
        if(res == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_get failed\n");
            abort();
        }
        //printf("getting Key: %s - %s\n", test_keys[i], res);
    }

}

void test_not_found_cap_rockyou(hashdb *db) {
    char *res = hashdb_get(db, "definitely not inside");
    if(res != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "definitely not inside - found (failure/must not happen)\n");
        abort();
    }
    //printf("definitely not inside - not found (success) rockyou\n");
}

void test_not_found_default_cap(hashdb *db)
{
    char *res = hashdb_get(db, "definitely not inside");
    if(res != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "definitely not inside - found (failure/must not happen)\n");
        abort();
    }
    //printf("definitely not inside - not found (success) default\n");
}

/* test append 14344392 keys */
void hashdb_test_append_rockyou(hashdb *db)
{
    size_t x = ROCKYOU_LINES-1;
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < ROCKYOU_LINES; i++, x--) {
        if(hashdb_add(db, test_keys[i], test_keys[x]) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_test_append_rockyou\n");
            abort();
        }
    }

}

/* test get 1000 keys */
void hashdb_test_get_1000_keys(hashdb *db) {

    for(size_t i = HASHDB_START_GET_FROM; i < HASHDB_START_GET_FROM + 1000; i++) {
        const char *res = hashdb_get(db, test_keys[i]);
        if(res == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_test_get_1000_keys");
            abort();
        }
    }

}

/* test get single keys */
void hashdb_test_get_key(hashdb *db)
{
    const char *res = hashdb_get(db, test_keys[HASHDB_START_GET_FROM]);
    if(res == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_test_get_key");
            abort();
    }
}

/* test get all keys */
void hashdb_test_get_rockyou(hashdb *db)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ROCKYOU_LINES; i++) {
        const char *res = hashdb_get(db, test_keys[i]);
        if(res == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_test_get_rockyou");
            abort();
        }
    }
}

void hashdb_test_del_rockyou(hashdb *db)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ROCKYOU_LINES; i++) {
        const char *res = hashdb_del(db, test_keys[i]);
        if(res == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_test_del_rockyou");
            abort();
        }

    }

}

void hashdb_test_del_default(hashdb *db)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < hashdb_cap(db); i++) {
        const char *res = hashdb_del(db, test_keys[i]);
        if(res == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: hashdb_test_del_rockyou");
            abort();
        }

    }
}


int main(void)
{
    timebot *bot = timebot_create(20);

   if(init_test_keys(ROCKYOU_PATH) != 0) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    hashdb *db = hashdb_create();


    /* enable constant so it don't execute the grow function */
    hashdb_enable_constant(db, true);
    timebot_standalone(bot, hashdb_test_fullfill, db, "test if hashdb is filled completely if growing is disabled");
    timebot_standalone(bot, test_not_found_default_cap, db, "test if not found works with default capacity");
    timebot_standalone(bot, hashdb_test_del_default, db, "delete HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAP entries");
    hashdb_enable_constant(db, false);
    /* disable constant so it executes the grow function */

    printf("after creation and adding 7 (HASHDB_DEFAULT_CAPACITY)\n");
    printf("\ncap:    %1lu   (should be 7)\n", hashdb_cap(db));
    printf("len:    %1lu   (should be 0)\n", hashdb_len(db));
    printf("filled: %2.1f (should be 0.0)\n", hashdb_filled_percent(db));

    // ensure capacity fits with lines in rockyou.txt
    hashdb_ensure_capacity(db, ROCKYOU_LINES * 2);
   

    timebot_append(bot, hashdb_test_append_rockyou, db, "adding 14.344.392 keys to hashdb");
    timebot_append(bot, hashdb_test_get_key, db, "get one key");
    timebot_append(bot, hashdb_test_get_1000_keys, db, "get 1000 keys");
    timebot_append(bot, hashdb_test_get_rockyou, db, "get all keys");
    timebot_append(bot, test_not_found_cap_rockyou, db, "key is not found with cap of 14.3 million entries");
    
    timebot_run(bot);

    printf("\nafter appending rockyou.txt\n");
    printf("cap: %lu\n", hashdb_cap(db));
    printf("len: %lu\n", hashdb_len(db));
    printf("filled: %f\n", hashdb_filled_percent(db));

    timebot_standalone(bot, hashdb_test_del_rockyou, db, "deleting all rockyou keys");


    hashdb_add(db, "testkey", "testdata");

    printf("\nafter deleting all and adding one\n");
    printf("cap: %lu\n", hashdb_cap(db));
    printf("len: %lu\n", hashdb_len(db));
    printf("filled: %f\n", hashdb_filled_percent(db));
    
    timebot_print_summery(bot);

    hashdb_destroy(db);

    destroy_keys();
    timebot_destroy(bot);
}
```

**timebot.h** (used by hashdb_test.c)

```
#ifndef _TIMEBOT_H
#define _TIMEBOT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct excecute_bundle {
    const char *description;
    const char *function_name;
    void (*run)(void*);
    void *arg;
    double runtime;
} excecute_bundle;

typedef struct timebot {
    excecute_bundle *exec_pool;
    int n;
    double capacity;
    double total_time;
    double longest_rtime;
    const char *longest_rtime_fname;
    int longest_function_name_length;
} timebot;

/*! @function
 @param n   number of preallocated executions
 @return    timebot pointer
*/
static timebot *timebot_create(size_t n)
{
    timebot *bot = (timebot *) calloc(1, sizeof *bot);
    if(bot == NULL) {
        perror("timebot_create");  /* this must not happen */
        abort();
    }

    bot->exec_pool = (excecute_bundle *) calloc(n, sizeof *bot->exec_pool);
    if(bot->exec_pool == NULL) {
        perror("timebot_create execution pool");
        abort();
    }

    return bot;
}

static void timebot_destroy(timebot *tb)
{
    free(tb->exec_pool);
    free(tb);
}



/* runs function with a argument and logs its runtime */
static void _get_runtime(excecute_bundle *bundle)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    bundle->run(bundle->arg);
    bundle->runtime =  (double) (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

static void _tb_append(timebot *tb, void (*func)(void *), void *arg, const char *name, const char *description)
{
    excecute_bundle *current = &tb->exec_pool[tb->n];
    size_t fname_len = strlen(name);

    if(fname_len > tb->longest_function_name_length) {
        tb->longest_function_name_length = fname_len;
    }

    current->function_name = name;
    current->run = func;
    current->arg = arg;
    current->description = description;

    tb->n++;
}

static void _tb_standalone(timebot *tb, void (*func)(void *), void *arg, const char *name, const char *description)
{
    _tb_append(tb, func, arg, name, description);
    excecute_bundle *current = &tb->exec_pool[tb->n-1];
    _get_runtime(current);
    current->run = NULL;
    current->arg = NULL;   
}

/* append to timebot's execution list */
#define timebot_append(tb, func, arg, desc) _tb_append(tb, func, arg, #func, desc)
#define timebot_standalone(tb, func, arg, desc) _tb_standalone(tb, func, arg, #func, desc)

/* runs all appended functions */
static void timebot_run(timebot *tb) {
    excecute_bundle *current;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tb->n; i++) {

        current = &tb->exec_pool[i];

        if(current->run != NULL) {
            _get_runtime(current);
            if(current->runtime > tb->longest_rtime) {
                tb->longest_rtime = current->runtime;
                tb->longest_rtime_fname = current->function_name;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* compare functions execution time */
static void timebot_compare(timebot *tb)
{
    excecute_bundle *current;
    printf("\nTimebot Summery:\n%*s\tTime\n", -tb->longest_function_name_length, "Function");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tb->n; i++) {
        current = &tb->exec_pool[i];
        printf("%*s\t%f sec (faster than %s by %f%%)\n", -tb->longest_function_name_length, current->function_name, current->runtime, tb->longest_rtime_fname,  100 - (current->runtime / tb->longest_rtime * 100));
    }
}

/* prints a summery of all executions */
static void timebot_print_summery(timebot *tb)
{
    excecute_bundle *current;
    printf("\nTimebot Summery:\n  %*s | Time\n", -tb->longest_function_name_length, "Function");
    printf("  --------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tb->n; i++) {
        current = &tb->exec_pool[i];
        if(current->run == NULL) {
            printf("  %*s | %f sec STANDALONE (%s)\n", -tb->longest_function_name_length, current->function_name, current->runtime, current->description);
        } else {
            printf("  %*s | %f sec (%s)\n", -tb->longest_function_name_length, current->function_name, current->runtime, current->description);
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: What has been your point coding this, benchmarking this? Shouldn't `hashdb_get()`(map, `hashdb_return()`) stop probing on NULL? What about *delete*s?

Comment: `hashdb_return()` just returns the addres of a `bucket`. How to handle this entry is up the caller. The benchmarking is done because I want to know how fast it can process the pairs. I will add the benchmarking code.

Comment: @greybeard `hashdb_return()` returns null if it has found nothing after searching the map

Comment: That's a lot of unwarranted probes in case of "unsuccesful searches".

Comment: "_overhead of about 4 to ..._", "_why bits?_" The point of the **sparse** library is it can get away with allocating less memory for a "boring" ("sparse") datastructure that mostly has empty values. Also, you probably want to track occupancy, and either signal fatal error or do a reallocation when there's more than ~ 80% occupancy. Otherwise probing is going to take a very, very long time to report that we no longer obey the sparsity assumption and nearly all cells are occupied.

Comment: @greaybeard Yes I see. But how can I improve this? With 14.xxx.xxx million entries I got 1.7 seconds from benchmarking thought the whole map. I mean this is not meant to be a database system. With 37 capacit ith 0.000003 seconds.

Comment: Specifically, this allocation seems light: `hashdb_ensure_capacity(db, ROCKYOU_LINES);`. If you're going with their 50% recommendation, then you'd want another `2 *` factor in there. And, sure, 75% full would be fine, too. It's when we venture into the nineties that probing gets ugly.

Comment: @J_H well that makes sense now from that perspective. I use a `loadfactor of 0.75` and every call to `hashdb_add` checks if `n` entries are `0.75` of capacity and if so then it reallocates and rehashes the map. `hashdb_del` call checks if it is `1 - 0.75` and then shrinks the map.

Comment: @J_H so the higher the ratio of `capacity` to `n` elements the better the performance because keys are more likely guaranteed to have an unique space or the quadratic probing needs less tries?

Comment: wholy moly I'v got `2.1 seconds` for alls inserts after setting the loadfactor to `0.5`. I did not understand that this can tune something... very impressing.

Comment: There is a probability distribution on probing. Sometimes you win after a single probe, or after two probes, and rarely it takes ten probes. But as load factor gets tighter, that whole distribution gets pushed out to the right, so "in expectation" the average number of probes might jump from 2.3 to 12.4 or something similarly ugly. Keeping the load factor sensible prevents probing overhead from getting out of hand.

Comment: The `hash_probe` macro doesn't look anything like the formula. The values could be precomputed. The next value could be computed from the preceding one with one multiplication less - probably dwarfed by mod. Where did you get that "alternating" probe sequence formula from? *Does* it cover all indices?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I have deleted my other comment. I am analyzing the code now.

Comment: mortytheshorty, Curious, why does `elfhash(const unsigned char *str)`, use `const`, but not `size_t fnv_hash(unsigned char *data, size_t size)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General Observations

Interesting question! As the comments show, a lot of room for learning!

Consistency! Some header files are using Doxygen Comments, other headers are not, some header files don't even have comments. Pick a style and stay with it. When you use Doxygen for one function in a file use it for all functions in the file.

Header files with commented out function prototypes (`hashdb.h`) are not ready for code review. I recommend using a configuration management system such as Git. You can store your files on GitHub. This allows you to delete code and be able to restore it if you want to.

When I was starting out as a software engineer it was common to run [lint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) on the code after it compiled, this found a lot of errors in the code. This isn't really necessary now if you use the proper compiler flags (for gcc -pedantic, -Wall, -Wextra, and -Wconversion for Visual Studio Warning Level3 or Level4). This allowed me to find some problems in the code such as a type mismatch between the prototype declarations of `elfhash(const unsigned char *str)` and the implementation of `elfhash(const unsigned char *str)`.

misc.h:

```
size_t elfhash(const unsigned char *str);
```

misc.c

```
unsigned long elfhash(const unsigned char *str)
```

**This particular mismatch problem is important because size_t is implementation dependent and may not use a `unsigned long` on all systems.**

Other type mismatches:

> timebot.h(71,44): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
> hashdb_test.c.c(187,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%1lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'size_t'
> hashdb_test.c(187,12): message : consider using '%zu' in the format string
> hashdb_test.c(188,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%1lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'size_t'
> hashdb_test.c(188,12): message : consider using '%zu' in the format string
> hashdb_test.c(204,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'size_t'
> hashdb_test.c(204,12): message : consider using '%zu' in the format string
> hashdb_test.c(205,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'size_t'
> hashdb_test.c(205,12): message : consider using '%zu' in the format string
> hashdb_test.c(214,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'size_t'
> hashdb_test.c(214,12): message : consider using '%zu' in the format string
> hashdb_test.c(215,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%lu' requires an argument of type 'unsigned long', but variadic argument 1 has type 'size_t'
> hashdb_test.c(215,12): message : consider using '%zu' in the format string

In the function `main()` should this really be the code?

```
   if(init_test_keys(ROCKYOU_PATH) != 0) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

or should it be

```
   if(init_test_keys(ROCKYOU_PATH) != 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

## Doxygen Comments

This is a great system for documenting the code, I reccomend that you either use it in the header files or the source files but not both. It is very hard to maintain 2 different sets of comments and keep them in sync.

## timebot.h

I recommend putting the actual C source code in `timebot.c` and only putting the data structure declarations and prototype functions in in `timebot.h`. While the code does a good job of protecting the functions with static declarations C source code generally isn't put into header files.

## Magic Numbers

The code already has a lot of symbolic constants and this is really good, but there is code where there are still raw numbers that need explanation:

misc.c

```
bool IsPrime(size_t n)
{
    if((n & 1) != 0) {
        for(size_t divisor = 3; divisor <= n / divisor; divisor += 2) {
            if((n % divisor) == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return (n == 2);
}

size_t GetHigherPrime(size_t n) {
    for(size_t i = (n | 1); i < LONG_MAX; i += 2) {
        if(IsPrime(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

size_t GetLowerPrime(size_t n) {
    for(size_t i = (n | 1); i < LONG_MAX; i -= 2) {
        if(IsPrime(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

size_t elfhash(const unsigned char *str)
{
    size_t   h = 0, high;
    while (*str)
    {
        h = (h << 4) + *str++;
        if ((high = h & 0xF0000000))
            h ^= high >> 24;
        h &= ~high;
    }
    return h;
}
```

## Variable Declarations

A best practice in most programming languages is to declare a single variable per line. In the C and C++ programming languages this best practice also suggests that each variable be initiated on that line as well since neither language provides default values for variables. It turns out that the lack of initialization is a source of many bugs (I have had to trace this error through someone else's code when I was merging libraries into an executable).

In the `elfhash` function above the code:

```
    size_t   h = 0, high;
```

would be better written if it was:

```
    size_t   h = 0;
    size_t   high = 0;
```

One of the reasons for putting each variable on its own line is that it improves readability and maintainability.

## While Loops Versus For Loops

The `for` loops in `fnv_hash_string(const char *str)` and `fnv_hash(unsigned char *data, size_t size)` should be while loops, at no point is the loop counter variable `i` used. Loop invariants should be moved out of the loop, and `i` is a loop invariant. An optimizing compiler might fix the performance in this code and it might not, there are also times that you can't use the optimization of the compiler such as when you are working on embedded systems.

```
size_t fnv_hash_string(const char *str)
{
    size_t hash;
    int i;
    for(i = 0, hash = FNV_OFFSET; *str != '\0'; str++, i++) {
        hash = hash ^ *str;
        hash = hash * FNV_PRIME;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

```
size_t fnv_hash_string(const char *str)
{
    size_t hash = FNV_OFFSET;
    while (*str)
    {
        hash = hash ^ *str;
        hash = hash * FNV_PRIME;
        str++;
    }

    return hash;
}
```

## DRY Code

There is a programming principle called the [Don't Repeat Yourself Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) sometimes referred to as DRY code. If you find yourself repeating the same code multiple times it is better to encapsulate it in a function. If it is possible to loop through the code that can reduce repetition as well.

The 2 hash functions in `misc.c`, `size_t fnv_hash_string(const char *str)` and `size_t fnv_hash(unsigned char *data, size_t size)` appear to be a duplication of the code, this may be a problem in the future, however, `fnv_hash()` is never called and can probably be removed. There doesn't seem to be a reason to ever use `fnv_hash()` since a size shouldn't ever be needed.

The functions `size_t GetHigherPrime(size_t n)` and `GetLowerPrime(size_t n)` could also be merged if a second parameter, `direction` is added.

```
#define HIGHERPRIME 2
#define LOWERPRIME -2
size_t GetOtherPrime(size_t n, int direction)
{
    for (size_t i = (n | 1); i < LONG_MAX; i += direction) {
        if (IsPrime(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: So I decided to put the comments inside the header files for the users opportunity to read it if they dont use doxygen. I did't not know that these are `doxygen QT style comments`. I saw them in some other code and noticed they are nicely shown by hovering over them in VS Code. I documented the `magic numbers` now, changed every the variable declarations to single lines and also change the hash code to use the `while loop`. Nice example for the `DRY Code` as I did not think about that i.e. `10 += -2 = 8`. I also changed the `return value` from the hash functions to uint64.

Comment: Can you explain when to use which type? I.e. size_t? Can I keep `size_t` for the prime functions?

Comment: @mortytheshorty The recommended uses of [size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) are loop counters, indexes in arrays and memory allocation sizes. Since the hash functions return an index into a dynamic array that is a good use. I don't see any reason to not to use size_t for the prime functions as well. Depending on the implementation size_t may be unsigned long or unsigned int.

Comment: okay so I changed the hash value type to `uint64_t` and keep the the `size_t` for those. Do you know a better approach for getting the index by quadratic probing? As @greybeard said this `hash_probe macro` has nothing to do with the formular but I hit everything with it as long as capacity is a prime number. But these are may mulitpliactions and divisions. I'm currently not familiar with those math orders and formulas. Any help with that?

Comment: 1) As I use your function above I get a warning for  `i += direction` because of `sign-conversion`. If I cast the direction to `size_t` it would be `ULONG_MAX-2` and that's not good. What should I do in this case? 2) Shouldn't `i < ULONG_MAX` be better as I use `size_t` as loop counter?

Answer (score 3):

Quadratic probing uses as the \$i\$th offset from the first probe index \$\pm 1^ic_2i^2+c_1i+c_0, c_2\ne 0\$ with parentheses inserted as deemed useful.
`(-1) * (i * i + 1) * (i / 2) * (i / 2)` does not implement this.
In C integer arithmetic disregarding overflows, this should be \$-i^2\lfloor\frac i2\rfloor^2\$, growing like \$-i^4\$.
Inline functions are less error prone than intricate macros - "non-branching":

```
/*! Return the probe index for the ith probe 
 *   for an item hashing to hash in a table of size capacity. */
size_t hash_probe(size_t hash, size_t i, size_t cap) {
        const int 
                c2[] = {-1, 1}, c1[] = {1, 1}, c0 = 0,
                odd = i & 1;
        return (hash + (c2[odd] * i + c1[odd]) * i + c0) % cap;
}
```

Neither the formula quoted nor what I tinkered with in `c2`, `c1` and `c0` in `size_t hash_probe()` gave me 4001 different results for `i` from 1 to 4001, inclusive, not even close.

Comment: It works only until capacity of 11. After that I get many results twice. Why is it not working as expected?

Comment: Please tell what you refer to using `it` in [above comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283787/quadratic-probing-hashmap-and-its-time-efficiency/283871?noredirect=1#comment564515_283871). Details on *not working* welcome.

Comment: I wrote my own `hash_probe` function and thought mine an yours do the same thing but somehow yours returns doublicate entries on increasing  `size_t i` until capacity and mine does this but wth `cap >= 13`. Capacity i.e. ` 7 or 11` work as expected that every result is in range `0-6 (for cap == 7) and `0-10 (for cap == 11)` if I loop from `i == 0 to i == cap). How can I show my hash_probe function? Edit my question or edit your answer?

Comment: How about an [SO question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I created an [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75714640/prime-number-based-quadratic-probing-function-only-hits-every-location-for-m) on StackOverflow:

Answer (score 3):

Minor stuff:

**`IsPrime(1)` is usually considered false**

```
bool IsPrime(size_t n) {
   ...
        // return 1;
        return n > 1;
```

**Unneeded `L`**

The `L` to insure that the constant is at least `long` is not needed.

```
//#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037UL
//#define FNV_PRIME  1099511628211UL
#define FNV_OFFSET 14695981039346656037U
#define FNV_PRIME  1099511628211U
```

IMO, such magic numbers are a tad more informative when written in hex as it readily shows 14695981039346656037  is a 64-bit number.

**Iffy code**

<strike>`calloc(1, sizeof *db);` is like `calloc(1, sizeof void);`.  Sure you want that?</strike>

Code `typedef`s `hashdb` 2 different ways.  This leads to *undefined behavior* as the pointer types are not *specified* as being compatible.

Instead of:

```
typedef void hashdb;                   // hashdb.h
typedef struct hashdb { ... } hashdb;  // hashdb_internal.h
```

Better and simpler to use `typedef struct hashdb hashdb;` and have  `hashdb_internal.h` include `hashdb.h`.

```
typedef struct hashdb hashdb;
```

Note that the *definition* of `struct hashdb` is only needed in `hashdb_internal.h`.

This makes for correct code and better type checking in public user usage.

Comment: I fixed `IsPrime`  and changes the macros. But `calloc(1, sizeof *db)` is correct since it does only include ` hashdb_internal.h` where `hashdb` is defined as `struct hashdb`.

Comment: @mortytheshorty Answer updated.  Do not define `hashdb` 2 different ways.  You can avoid UB and hide `struct hashdb` from the public by using `typedef struct hashdb hashdb;` in  `hashdb.h`.

Comment: Ah didn‘t know that's allowed.